# Tornado web server in webfaction

Tags: python, django, tornado, instagram, webfaction

I am starting with web development. I am trying to develop and webapp using the Instagram API and Django. I was looking that a lot of people it's using Tornado Web Server for Real Time Subscriptions. So I am using Webfaction as a host and found this code so I can wrap my Django project with the "WSGI Container" that Tornado Web Server provides:

```
import os
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.wsgi
import tornado.web
import sys
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
sys.path.append('/path/to/project')

class HelloHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write('Hello from tornado')

def main():
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings' # path to your settings module
    wsgi_app = tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer(django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler())
    tornado_app = tornado.web.Application(
            [
                    ('/hello-tornado', HelloHandler),
                    ('.*', tornado.web.FallbackHandler, dict(fallback=wsgi_app)),
            ]
    )
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(tornado_app)
    http_server.listen(8080)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So I run this python script inside my Webfaction server and everytime I try to access "http://mywebsite.com/hello-tornado/" does not seem to work. I know I am running that Tornado web server on that port but do not know how too access from the browser or something like that. What I am doing wrong here? Thanks for your help and patience. Will cyber high-five for every answer.

EDIT: What I am really trying to do is that I want to receive all the calls from the subscriptions that I make with the Instagram RealTime Subscription API through Tornado, for that I have a callback url "http://mysite.com/sub" and I want to be able to receive through Tornado.

Comment: what is the main webserver running on your webfaction box? If its apache you can add a proxy directive to redirect requests to http://mywebsite.com/hello-tornado to http://localhost:8080/hello-tornado (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)

Comment: I'd found that is Apache2, do I have to configure this in the "httpd.conf"?

Comment: yes, you'll need to enable mod_proxy and add the relevant proxypass directives there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are starting the server at port 8080, Web browsers use port 80 by default, try using: http://mywebsite.com:8080/hello-tornado

if you want to use port 80 and you already have a web server running in the box you can try following Ali-Akber Saifee suggestion, or run the WSGI application directly from the server, using something like mod_python (http://www.modpython.org), you will lose the ability to run Tornado code, but Django will work.

Comment: Definitely this worked, thanks guys. Cyber HIGH FIVE for both.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom app (listening on port), note the port that is assigned to your app then configure tornado to serve on that port: http_server.listen(my port)
You can also avoid tornado and start directly by installing a django app.